# Is there a way in Vim to paste a line so it pushes the current line down?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

The default pasting behavior in vim is to put the line directly below the cursor. Pasting "Line 2" on "Line 1" results like this:

```
Line 1

Line 2
```

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

Is it possible to paste lines in vim with this result occurring instead?

```
Line 2
Line 1
```

Comment: The answer to this is so easy to find with a simple `::help p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the paste before: `P` (capital P) to paste before the cursor.

If you want the cursor to stay on the original line you could also do: `gP`

In opposition to paste after: `p` (small p) to paste after the cursor.

More information with: `:help P`, `:help gP` or `:help put`.

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR:**

Use `P` (capital P) instead of `p` (lowercase p)

---

**Long Answer:**

Looking at the [vim help section](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#p) we can learn a cool few things about the "put" command:

- keymap can be capitalized to put text before the cursor (most keybindings uses this technique, look at `o` and `O`)
- you can provide a count (handy to copy multiple times a template)
- you can specify the register it gets its value from (e.g. I use the [void buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register) `"_dP` when I need to paste but not yank the value I overwrite)

```
                        p put E353 E1240
["x]p           Put the text [from register x] after the cursor
            [count] times.

                            P
["x]P           Put the text [from register x] before the cursor
            [count] times.
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! High-quality answers typically include explanations and references to documentation that help querents understand and further explore the answer. Feel free to [edit] to include additional information!

Comment: Done. Sorry, still new to this :)